# SQL Server Database to share with team?

Tags: sql-server, git, svn, tfs, azure-devops

I'm looking for a method to share SQL Server Database's structures and their contents/datas with the team?
We're currently using TFS 2013. If it's the case we can switch to SVN/GIT etc, too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of data do you wish to share, and how much data is there?

Answer (score 1):

You should try `Sql Server Data Tools`, with Visual Studio Database project. Works really good. Also you can store code in any version control you like

Answer (score 1):

Redgate's tools are the best solution for database based operations. They've got an SQL source control solution which can be used with almost every software versioning system that there is (including TFS). It can be seen pricey but it's worth its price. (And you access all the features via SSMS.)

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to connect to same database, than your best alternative is to generate SQL Scripts for creating database structure and populating it with data. Depending on volume of data it might not be efficient to share it through scripts.

When working on a school project with my classmates we scripted out database structure and limited number of data elements and placed in Tortoise Hq.

If you have large database that you want to share with others that you already developed and populated, it is best to just backup your database and give them the backup file to restore on their system. After that you can share scripts that modify the data and structures. My preference to have scripts that generate or alter database structure in version control software and data somewhere else.